# Running Pymol on Windows from .whl install

Tags: python, windows, pymol

I've managed to install pymol on windows following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) and using the file Pmw‑2.0.1‑py2‑none‑any.whl from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymol)

Various folders have appeared in `C:\Users\Python27\Lib\site-packages` (`Pmw` and `Pmw-2.0.1.dist-info`). However, I can't actually work out how to run pymol.

It used to be provided as a .exe format which could just be run in the usual way for windows applications. The folders that have installed just contain lots of python scripts, but I can't find anything which actually launches the programme.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not the official way but it works :)

- Download both the appropriate `pymol` and `pymol-launcher` file.
- Install `pymol` via `pip`
- change file extention of pymol-launcher to `.zip` (or unzip it straight)
- get `pymol.exe` and make sure to have either `pymol##.dll` (`##` is your version number) in your path or in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Did it work for you?

I took another approach. NOTE! I am using **Anaconda2 (python 2.7.13)** under Windows 8.1

1. First download the appropriate files from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymol](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pymol)

> Pmw-2.0.1-py2-none-any.whl
>
> pymol-1.8.6.1-cp27-cp27m-win_am d64.whl
>
> pymol_launcher-1.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

3. Start Command Prompt (Admin) via right-click on windows start button and navigate to your python installation directory
4. Enter the following lines (adapt to your installation of python)

C:\Users\David\Anaconda2>`Scripts\pip.exe install Pmw-2.0.1-py2-none-any.whl`

C:\Users\David\Anaconda2>`Scripts\pip.exe install pymol-1.8.6.1-cp27-cp27m-win_am d64.whl`

C:\Users\David\Anaconda2>`Scripts\pip.exe install pymol_launcher-1.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

Now just launch pymol via pymol.exe that was created in the same directory.