# Failed to install package 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, sklearn-pandas

After a whole day struggle, here I finally give up and ask this question. I know this may not be totally appropriate to ask this question but I'm not able to install sklearn on PyCharm and even can't install it using pip.

**Config:** Windows 10, Pycharm community edition, Python 3.6

**Here is a screen of the error:**

[image: screen of the error (Failed to install package 'sklearn')]

**The error messsage:**

```
running build_clib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying 
from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib
building 'libsvm-skl' library
compiling C sources
creating build\temp.win32-3.6
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\sklearn
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\sklearn\svm
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\sklearn\svm\src
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\sklearn\svm\src\libsvm
```

Comment: Can you tell us your configuration ? And see my answer, this is how I installed it on windows, tell me if it works for you

Comment: Did you install numpy and scipy?

Comment: I am using windows 10, Pycharm community version and python 3.6

Comment: Yes I installed numpy and scipy

Comment: You have same configuration than me so I think it should work

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **download the wheel corresponding to your configuration** [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn)  and **install it with**:

`pip install some-package.whl`

If you have problem to install the wheel read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest other way to install, is to use the command line. Open the command line, change the directory to your Pycharm directory and install it using pip.

You can also try reinstalling numpy.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. on doing this it always showed python stopped working