# Is there an easy way of installing PySide 2 for Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, pyside2

Is there any way to "simply" install PySide 2 on Windows 10?
If not are there tutorials for installing it?

Can I export a PySide 2 project to an `.exe` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a somewhat recent version of Python 3, you can now also do

```
pip install PySide2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to easily install Pyside2 on Windows using conda.

```
# Enable conda-forge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
# Install PySide2
conda install pyside2
```

For more instructions, see [this link](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2017/08/28/pyside2-easy-install/)

You can freeze your Python programs into standalone executables using Pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1):

Since recently, 'wheels' (for Windows, Linux, OS X) are available at http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/

Here you can read how to install `whl` files: [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

At the moment of writing this response, PySide2 seems to be still under development, not yet completely production ready. Hopefully will be soon, we all are looking forward to it.