# How to use pip to install .whl in python shell?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I  have downloaded a wheel file for Python module. The .whl file is now in the same folder where Scripts folder is located. C:/Python27. The name of the .whl file is shown as below:

```
pandas-0.22.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Please tell me how to use pip for installing the .whl file in Python console (not the command line). Something similar to installing tweepy.

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5>python2.exe
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(['install','tweepy'])
```

Answer (score -1):

In your windows explorer, go to the directory where you have wheel.exe installed, if you don't type `pip install wheel.exe` in you command prompt. Once in the folder where you have `wheel.exe`, create a document using notepad, title `local.bat`. This creates a command prompt directed to that specific folder. Open this, and type: `pip install your_file.whl`.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking

Answer (score -2):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/6552776)!

*I'm citing the answer I've linked:*

I just used the following which was quite simple. First open a console then cd to where you've downloaded your file like some-package.whl and use

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

Note: if pip.exe is not recognized, you may find it in the "Scripts" directory from where python has been installed. If pip is not installed, this page can help:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/6552776)

*Note: for clarification*
If you copy the `*.whl` file to your local drive (ex. **C:\some-dir\some-file.whl**) use the following command line parameters --

```
pip install C:/some-dir/some-file.whl
```

Comment: OP is asking for the console solution, not command line

Answer (score -2):

```
import pip._internal as pip
package_names=['name_of_package', 'requests']
pip.main(['install'] + [package_names] + ['--upgrade'])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes