# How do I install scipy for Python3.4?

Tags: python, scipy

When I try to install scipy for 3.4 it throws this error when I run this command:

```
sudo pip3.4 install scipy
```

https://www.pastiebin.com/5a7c65d7e44fe

I was able to get it to install with Python 3.6 but not 3.4.. which I need.

Comment: It seems your sys is not read for scipy-install-from-sources (BLAS/LAPACK). Either look out for a system-package (apt, rpm,  ...) or use the binary-wheels from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/1.0.0) (```scipy-1.0.0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (md5, pgp) ``` for example).

Comment: Thanks @sascha, how do I install that wheel file after downloading it?

Comment: [Like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) (of course make sure you use the correct pip-binary)

Comment: "scipy-1.0.0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."   Running Ubuntu 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Installing Scipy or Numpy from scratch is usually hard work. At best try a distribution that already has it installed (WinPython, Anaconda). If you are on Linux install the packages that come with your [distro](https://www.scipy.org/install.html#install-system-wide-via-a-linux-package-manager). On Windows you can also grab the wheels at [Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy).