# How to manually installing library in Python 3.7 or 3.6

Tags: python

Using corporate network that blocking pip -m install xxxx function.
   Showing the message below in CMD :

> Retry xxx fail to connect xxx...

Trying to do :

- Download the package > put in the folder > use manual method to
  install if it exist
- Pass corporate network security rule if there is
  some code are able to do for it

R works normally for installing library (Except setting webdriver through selenium, same problem with network security problem)

I am beginner of Python. Is there another alternative solution?

Comment: You can download packages as wheel files (`.whl`) then [install them locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file). I would also suggest to your IT that they whitelist the package server (https://pypi.python.org/pypi) so you can use the normal workflow.

Comment: What library? For example, numpy needs specifically compiled on your machine

Comment: You can use python -m pip install youmodule or python3 -m pip install youmodule

Comment: Talk to your it department and get them to open the network for you.

Comment: @Narendra Read the question

Comment: @cricket_007 okkk thanks got it...

Comment: Thank you CoryKramer , cricket_007 , thebjorn , Narenda .  1. When py -m pip install operate > it goes to [link]https://pypi.python.org/pypi to downloading library .--> Whistlist or opening network filter for this URL solve the problem.  2 . If USE downloading and install by manually , `py -m pip install wheel` > `py -m pip install C:\xxx\xxx.whl  ` .   I am going to use numpy , pandas , selenium , beautiful soup . webdriver proxy error will be another problem though .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually download wheel (.whl) files for Windows from [this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). It contains most of the popular packages of Python for Windows Platform. Then you can install it using pip by providing the path to your .whl file:

```
pip install "C:\Python Packages\opencv_python-3.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
```

In this example I've installed the OpenCV library which is present in Python Packages directory in C drive.

Comment: Thankyou Mushif . Unfortunately , www.lfd.uci.edu doesn't provide .whl file for selenium .

Comment: Napbien: use [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to download .whl file for selenium. Scroll down and you'll find **selenium-3.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl** file.