# pywifi can't be installed on python

Tags: python, pip, installation

I tried to install pywifi through pip in python but the system says:

> You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip'.
>   command. Collecting pywifi Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement pywifi (from versions: ) .
>   No matching distribution found for pywifi

So I'm wondering how I should get it work?

Comment: Try upgrading pip using 'pip install --upgrade pip' so that it can find pywifi ?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade You're pip through: `pip install --upgrade pip`

check which version pip running  : `pip -V`

after that install pywifi: `pip install pywifi`

if above commands wouldn't work download the source file from here [pywifi](https://pypi.org/project/pywifi/#files)     switch to downloaded directory through cd, run cmd: `pip install pywifi-1.1.10-py3-none-any.whl`
here is the link to install .whl file [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

may be it would help for you're problem.

Comment: I was informed "pywifi-1.1.10-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: Do you sucessfully install pywifi?

Comment: yes, i'm able to install through pip, .whl file format and i'm using ubuntu16,pip 10.0.1

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: i'm using python3, trying to install on python2.7 but getting error (No matching distribution found for pywifi)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nowadays installaing pywifi via pip is problem. Upgrading pip is also not an option.

```
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch se-toolkit]$ pip --version 
pip 10.0.1 
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch se-toolkit]$ pip install pywifi
Collecting pywifi
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywifi (from versions: 1.0.2.linux-x86_64)
No matching distribution found for pywifi
```

I would suggest to clone (or download the source) it into your python's site-packages directory, then install it.

```
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch se-toolkit]$ cd lib/python2.7/site-packages/
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch site-packages]$ git clone https://github.com/awkman/pywifi.git
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch site-packages]$ cd pywifi/
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch pywifi]$ pip install .
...
Installing collected packages: comtypes, pywifi
Successfully installed comtypes-1.1.4 pywifi-1.1.10
```

then use it.

```
(se-toolkit) [ziya@ziya2018arch pywifi]$ python
 Python 2.7.14 (default, Apr 16 2018, 20:08:15) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180406] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pywifi
>>>
```