# Where to place wheel file for installation using pip?

Tags: python, pip

Where to place wheel file for installation using pip?

I want to install NumPy on Windows 7 on Python 3.6.2, using Christoph Gohlke's wheel:

```
numpy-1.14.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl.
```

The link at [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file#27909082) says I can install it using pip with the following command:

```
pip install C:/some-dir/some-file.whl
```

My question is:  where should I place the wheel file prior to installing it?  Should it be placed in the Python folder C:\Program Files\Python36\ or can I place the wheel file at any arbitrary location and still have it install correctly?  I assume the actual installation will be in the Python36 folder to enable importing into Python, but I don't want to mess up the installation by putting the wheel file in the wrong place.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is you can place it anywhere on your computer.  On Windows, install it from the Python command prompt with:

py -m pip install full_path_to_Package