# Conda - installing tensorflow from a .whl file behind a firewall

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I have got an **Anaconda3 with Python 3.6 (Spyder)** environments, trying to install `tensorflow`, however, can't utilize the standard pip installation due to company firewall.

Furthermore, I can't create an anaconda environment for the same reason. What I am trying to do is to install tensorflow directly from the `whl` file (which I have downloaded from the official website), using the following command:

`C:\Users\me>pip install --no-deps tensorflow-1.8.0-cps36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
which leads to 'Requirement **_ looks like a filename but the file does not exist' -> _** is not supported wheel on this platform.

When I try to run via:
`conda install --no-deps tensorflow-1.8.0-cps36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

I get Solving environment: `failed, CondaHTTPError: ... etc.` - probably due to the same firewall reason.

Now, is there any way to install the .whl without encountering the firewall restrictions?

Thank you vm guys.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the full error message `'Requirement ___ looks like a filename but the file does not exist' -> ___ is not supported wheel on this platform`? I think it's been mangled slightly in your post because you didn't use a code block.

Answer (score 3):

I had some success with this in my company (which also doesn't allow internet access by Anaconda package manager)

I found this site:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

where you can download wheel files for a number of python packages.  You can then use PIP to install the wheel packages locally .

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file?rq=1)