# I can't install libs via pip install filename.whl

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem with installing libraries using pip install .whl

This is my environment info:

`conda version : 4.10.1`

`conda-build version : 3.20.5`

`python version : 3.8.5.final.0`

`virtual packages : __cuda=10.2=0`

My OS is Windows 10

I have downloaded the whl file from [this website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely), just like it was shown in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361143/conda-installing-tensorflow-from-a-whl-file-behind-a-firewall)

But I always get this error

`ERROR: GDAL-3.2.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed pip, my env updated to python `3.9`, even though conda shows python version as `3.8.5`.

After noticing the problem was the python version, I downloaded the `.whl` file according to python `3.9` and installed successfully