# No module named install

Tags: module, installation, pygame

Yes you read it right! 
I am trying to install pygame, so I downloaded the ***whl*** file and copied it to my project's folder, in the command prompt I navigated to the folder and entered

```
python -m install --user pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

Now if you can help me here that would be really appreciated, why is the error so rare that I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: You forgot pip: `python -m pip install --user pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`. BTW, pygame 1.9.3 is the latest version.

Answer (score 9):

Python doesn't have a module called "**install**". The module you're looking for is probably **pip**.

Just type in the command prompt:

```
python -m pip install --user pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

And pygame should start being installed.