# Can't install pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am fairly new to using pip and python. I installed other libraries in python but can't install pandas. It gives lots of error after 22 percent installation. See the errors in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVVSg.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't show screenshots of the error message, you need to copy and paste the full error message in your question

Comment: `pip uninstall pandas`
uninstall and install pandas @ Mazhar Ali
`pip install pandas==0.23.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing numpy first, maybe pandas installation will work after.

```
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```

If it does not work, try installing specific versions of pandas, like:

```
pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image you have inserted the problem is with your internet speed. If I were you I would download pandas from [official website](https://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html). You can install it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file). Also on [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) website you will find other packages that needs to be installed in order for pandas to work.