# How to install the Python package without the Internet

Tags: python

There is a python 2.7 build (Python 2.7.14 (default, Jan 16 2018, 16:11:42) [MSC v.1800 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32) with the pip 9.0 and wheel packages installed.

Windows 7. No MSVC compiler. There is no Internet, only a flash drive.

Need a package pillow. On the official website there is an egg. I can not install the package - can not find the DLL.

What I tried:

1. I tried to unpack egg in the site-packages directory.
2. python -m pip install "D: \ ShadowProg \ Pillow-5.3.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl"

I took precompiled wheel from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow

The error in both cases is the same:

```
from PIL import Image

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "C:\FreeCAD 0.17\bin\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 64, in

from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Installation without compiler is highly desirable. Please advise what to do?

Comment: See answer to [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file). I've used it to install pillow on my Windows 7-based system in the past (with no compiler installed).

Answer (score 1):

Just spent ages with same problem - need to install Twisted on an offline machine with Windows 10.

Finally what have I done:

1. Find another machine with same OS, internet and VC++ (needed to install Twisted)
2. Install all needed packages on that machine into `virtualenv`
3. Copy full virtualenv folder to destination PC

You paths should be exactly the same! If on source machine virtual env was `c:\myproject\venv`, it should remain on destination PC! Otherwise you will need some manual work with fixing paths, which I believe you would prefer to avoid.

Also take care - Python versions should be the same. I failed with 32bit/64bit versions at first