# Locally downloading pandas fails on "cannot import name 'ndarray'"

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I need to run code on a remote machine with no internet. 
My code includes pandas and numpy.

I downloaded the numpy+pandas libraries locally to the same folder and used it. 
But when I try to run the code (with pandas in a local folder) I get a`cannot import name 'ndarray'` error.

Help

Answer (score 1):

you can download the whl file and and copy it to your remote machine without internet and install it using.

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

link to download whl files for windows

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

from this question: [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: I passed the files themselve without any issue. but when i imported pandas (which is a local library there) i got "cannot import name 'ndarray'"

Comment: form what i understand pandas in itself uses numpy and maybe it is unable to find numpy it that folder from where pandas is importing