# How to solve OS Error to import soundfile library

Tags: python, python-3.x, soundfile

I am struggling to rectify this error

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-ae75db7b0c22>", line 4, in <module>
    import soundfile as sf

  File "...\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 163, in <module>
    _path, '_soundfile_data', _libname))

OSError: cannot load library 'c:\users\ishpreet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_soundfile_data\libsndfile64bit.dll': error 0x7e
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `soundfile` library is mis-installed, the Python code is present but it's just a wrapper for a native dll which is missing.

The library's community and bug tracker is generally the better place to look for these issues, and indeed [it has an issue open indicating that pip 20 mis-installs soundfile (and others)](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/issues/253) as it grabs the pure-python package instead of the wheel with precompiled libraries.

You may want to either:

- wait it out
- explicitly install the proper wheel
- downgrade to pip 19.3

Comment: What is meant by "explicitly install the proper wheel"?

Comment: Download the correct (binary) wheel package for your platform, then [use pip to install that file specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/8182118). Pip can't grab the wrong package if it doesn't get to choose.