# pip install from private repo but requirements from PyPi

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I would like to install a package from private repo but when I run this:

```
pip install myapp -i https://myrepo.net/pypi/myfeed/simple
```

I got this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myapp (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for myapp
```

I assume this is because requirements for this package are not in the private repo, so I tried to add extra-index-url

```
pip install myapp -i https://myrepo.net/pypi/myfeed/simple --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi
```

But I got the exact same error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the private repo have a ```requirements.txt```?

Comment: @Kshitij what do you mean? Is this a file for the entire repo? Or do you mean for the myapp package ?

Comment: The requirements for the package must be in a requirements file so that ```pip``` can install these for running the package.

Comment: I did the build using poetry, I have a tar.gz and a .whl. Do you mean I need a requirement.txt next to these files?

Comment: If you have a ```.whl``` file try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file0)

Comment: The error seems to indicate that a compatible distribution of `myapp` does not exist on your private repo. Can you include the output of `pip install myapp -i https://myrepo.net/pypi/myfeed/simple  --verbose`?

Comment: Thanks @DustinIngram, the --verbose option makes me know that the version of python specified in myapp package is not compatible with the one installed in the virtualenv where I tried to install the package.. I'm a dumb guy :-(
But the error message could be more precise..

Comment: Glad to hear that resolved it. I've added that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that either `myapp` was not found on your index at all, or that a compatible distribution of `myapp` does not exist - for example, it requires a different version of Python than you are attempting to install with.

Running `pip` with the `--verbose` flag should tell you why it wasn't able to install `myapp`:

```
pip install myapp -i https://myrepo.net/pypi/myfeed/simple  --verbose
```