# importing python package -beginner question

Tags: python, file, installation, pip, python-module

I downloaded a package online from https://pypi.org/project/Random-Word/#description
its a random English word file. I downloaded it using pip install. it is a .whl file when downloaded. However in the project description he lists his basic usage as a .py file... I'm not sure how to import it into my program because its installed as a .whl file and the module isn't found when I try to import it.

Is there a way to convert .whl files to .py files in order for my program to see it as a module, be able to import it and use it in a program? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it like this:

```
pip(3) install random-word
```

Create a .py file and place the following in it:

```
from random_word import RandomWords
r = RandomWords()
print(r.get_random_word())
```

Then run the PY file:

```
python(3) <file>.py
```

Essentially, you need to `import RandomWords` from the `random_word` directory, instead if just `import RandomWords`

Comment: I installed it on cd pip install --user Random_Word-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl would this way use your method as well?

Comment: i guess im confused on how python or the cd is able to know that Random_Word-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl  is the same as random-word? they're not spelled the same way am i missing something here?

Comment: To use the package, just pip(3) install <package> and you'll be able to use it. Some packages use classes, so you will need to from <package> import <class>

Comment: are you putting pip(3) install Random_Word-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl  in the cmd prompt? i'm getting an error saying ERROR: unknown command "(3)".

Comment: there's pip and then there's pip3. you either pip install <package> or pip3 install <package>, either will do. For this one, pip(3) install random_word

Comment: okay i used pip install random_word and it looks like it installed it. I created the .py file and this error popped up ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomWords' from 'random_word'

Comment: If you executed this command: "pip install random-word" or this command: "pip3 install random-word", then you should be able to use this: "from random_word import RandomWords". Can you try this, to see if it is installed: "pip(3) show random-word"

Comment: the cmd prompt shows all the information from where i got it from ect and a short description of where it is. So it is installed. However I'm trying to import it into a pycharms program. i type it just as: from random_word import RandomWords and its greyed out. When i hover over the word random_word and RandomWords it says unresolved reference. when i execute it in pycharms it says Error: cannot import name 'RandomWords' from 'random_word'. is there a certain place where the .py file should be located maybe its a path issue? side not i really appreciate you taking the time to help me thus far.

Comment: I've never used pycharm except for a school project, can you try doing so with a regular py file outside of pycharm? maybe then we can tell if its pycharm causing the issue.

Comment: how would i do that? can i create a .py file from the cmd prompt?

Comment: Do you have any experience with jupyter notebooks? Its the only other editor i can think of and im not sure how to create a .py file there only .text and .ipynb.

Comment: Nope, never used it. I have the text extension on chrome os: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?hl=en, and nano on linux (sudo apt-get install nano)

Comment: Okay, i have downloaded the chrome extension to try it your way. Would you just type what you said before and save it as a .py file? or is there a specific way for the extension?

Comment: Type the example from my original comment, and save it as file.py. then run it with python (python3 file.py)

Comment: I've created the file however i'm having trouble figuring out how to run it on this extension.  Is there a keyboard short cut for it?

Comment: Assuming it is in your python directory, you'd run it in your terminal.