# Unable to install open cv using pip on Python 3.9

Tags: python, opencv

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mmusa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z5zd5j52\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mmusa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z5zd5j52\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mmusa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wre2z2vk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\mmusa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zf5z8fdj\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\mmusa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zf5z8fdj\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\python\python.exe' 'e:\python\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\mmusa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zf5z8fdj\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I get this error while installing opencv. I have upgraded my pip and I am currently using Python 3.9. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The important part of this error message is missing.  Do you have build tools installed on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**right now openCV is not supporting python 3.9**

*its better to use earlier version of python, like 3.5 so everything is in original and stable*

Answer (score 2):

Note the [opencv project readme](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#supported-python-versions) does not yet state support for Python 3.9

> Supported Python versions Python 3.x compatible pre-built wheels are
> provided for the officially supported Python versions (not in EOL):
>
> - 3.6
> - 3.7
> - 3.8

Without prebuilt wheels, you'll need to build it yourself. Make sure you have proper [build tools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) installed on your system.

Also note:

> on Windows, make sure you have [Visual C++ redistributable 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
> installed. If you are using older Windows version than Windows 10 and
> latest system updates are not installed, [Universal C Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) might be
> also required.

Alternatively, you can try downloading an [unofficial wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) for opencv (and other dependencies) for Python 3.9 and [installing from wheel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.9 is supported in the latest version of opencv.
[source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here for downloading modern machine learning libraries(TensorFlow, sci-kit learn)So saw the TensorFlow documentation(official) it was indicating that we should python 3.3-3.8 for installing. I tried that and fortunately, it worked. Hope it works for you! So according to me, you should also install python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help.

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

`pip3 install opencv-python`