# pygame zero will not download and will error out

Tags: python, windows, pip, pygame, pgzero

Whenever I try to download pygame zero, with the command `pip install pgzero`, it gives me this message.

```
Collecting pgzero
  Using cached pgzero-1.2-py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.0 MB)
Collecting pygame<2.0,>=1.9.2
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cdujr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cdujr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\cdujr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-5gmcv9l4'
         cwd: C:\Users\cdujr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\cdujr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\cdujr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\cdujr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\cdujr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zsy7lmsk\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What do I do? Ive tried uninstalling, and then reinstalling, but it didn't work.

Comment: You are trying to install pygame 1.9.6 on Python 3.9. This will not work. Install a pre-built wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). You'll want `pygame‑1.9.6‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl` to satisfy pgzero dependencies.

Comment: It gives me a WHL file. What do I open the file with?

Comment: Use `pip install path-to-your-whl-file.whl`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/7675174) for more information.