# How to install the shapely package in Python 2021

Tags: python

I cant manage to install the Shapely package for Python.

I have tried pip install shapely, installing from a wheel, I have made sure that I am using the correct wheel version (Python 3.8 64 bits), I have updated pip, I have removed and reinstalled Python, I have downloaded the Microsoft Build Tools and yet when I try to install from the wheel I get a message that the wheel is not supported. I dont get it.

Anybody ?

Comment: Could someone please point out whats wrong with my question ? Thank you.

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Note also that there's really no such thing as "Python 2021".

Comment: You can get a pre-built version of the module from Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and installing it. Also see [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```py
pip install pipwin
pipwin install shapely
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you creating a new environment and installing shapely there. If you use Anaconda distribution you can use Anaconda navigator for that. In the navigator click "Environments" and click "Create". Then one-click the new environemnt and select "All" to find all packages you need.

If this doesn't work foryou, you can create a new env also via Prompt.