# Installing python through company Firewall (Spyder and Python)

Tags: python, keras

I have win7 with Python 3.8.5 installed. I use Spyder. I am trying to install Keras but standards precedures does'nt work for me due to Company firewall. My company computer is very sensitive. So, **how do I install Keras from Spyder behind company firewall?**

I tried following these steps
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-install-keras-in-anaconda

There must be a way where I can download some files and copy those to my computer?

compuyrt information

[image]
[image]

Comment: A company machine should have [Win 10 by now](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962). Our Win 7 machines aren't allowed to have *any* internet access anymore; if you *have to* use this machine anyways, you can still install packages "offline" from whl files, see e.g. https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I have now downloaded the file? Would care to guide e a bit on how to install

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27885397/10197418) sets you on track :)

Comment: "ERROR: tensorflow-1.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." Do u have any idea why?

Comment: seems like the Python 3.7 version, maybe this one works for you: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (there's also a CPU-only version [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl)).

Comment: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013].... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are my recommendation for the same:

- Open your own computer which has windows installed on it and you have no firewall restrictions on it.
- run the following command in any empty directory
  `pip download tensorflow keras -d .`
- copy that same folder to company computer using a usb
- from there enter the following commands in copied directory
  `pip install tensorflow keras --no-index --find-links=.`

please consider that here are the following possiblities but are less likely to happen:

- company computer is a different architecture computer (you need to make sure that your and company computer are both the same architecture)
- company computer does not support (AVX instruction set)

Comment: probably not. I try

Comment: no mac does not work because it will download binaries for mac. how about you setup a windows virtual machine on your mac if you have a intel mac. and it will be really helpful if you could tell info about win7 machine. because then i can make it such thaf this will work for you

Comment: https://youtu.be/qoDO8PVRPIA please watch this and try it on you system machine and then attach screenshot with your question