# I am trying to install bcml library but it errors

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-3.9

I am trying to install something but it keeps giving me errors, this is the command:
`pip3 install bcml`

I have tried to upgrade my pip, setuptools, but it keeps giving me errors.
This is what shows up when I try and execute:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools>pip3 install bcml
Collecting bcml
  Using cached bcml-3.10.1-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl (18.8 MB)
Collecting pywebview~=3.6.3
  Using cached pywebview-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (351 kB)
Collecting oead~=1.2.4
  Using cached oead-1.2.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (978 kB)
Collecting aamp~=1.4.1
  Using cached aamp-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (337 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.2
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [265 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
      setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scarl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running dist_info
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win32-3.9
      creating build\src.win32-3.9\numpy
      creating build\src.win32-3.9\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\users\scarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 499, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 491, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
          return old_setup(**new_attr)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in run
          egg_info.run()
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24, in run
          self.run_command("build_src")
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in run
          self.build_sources()
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
          self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
          sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
          source = func(extension, build_dir)
        File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 650, in get_mathlib_info
          st = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link
          self._link(body, headers, include_dirs,
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 161, in _link
          return self._wrap_method(old_config._link, lang,
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 95, in _wrap_method
          ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 137, in _link
          (src, obj) = self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 104, in _compile
          src, obj = self._wrap_method(old_config._compile, lang,
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 95, in _wrap_method
          ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
          self.spawn(args)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ar11i87\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 505, in spawn
          return super().spawn(cmd, env=env)
        File "C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5zi0nmxu\numpy_bfc579247c784570b8bf0b27259d9e90\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 90, in <lambda>
          m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
      TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to execute the command: `pip3 install bcml`

I have tried to upgrade my resources

I have python 3.9

Comment: May I know why you are installing python library from visual studio build tools path?

Comment: I want to install the BOTW Randomizer mod onto my game and it was recommended that I take these steps.

Comment: How about you download the .whl file manually from bcml pypi website, try installing it the file manually to make sure no files are being loss. can refer how to install manually from here >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/12128167

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use python 3.9 with this package, it has requirements only available on Python `3.7.x` or `3.8.x`.

For full installation instructions for this package, check out the [wiki article](https://zeldamods.org/wiki/Help:Tools/BCML)

> BCML requires Python 3.8.10 or 3.7.9, and the x64 Visual C++ redistributable. When you open the Python installer, there will be a checkbox that says `Add Python to PATH`. You **MUST** check this box, or else BCML can't be installed. From here, continue as normal, and install the x64 Visual C++ redistributable.
>
> Open a command prompt anywhere (if you don't know how, just type cmd into Windows Search).
>
> Run pip install bcml (in normal cmd, **NOT** the python console). You should see a bunch of progress bars, and then a success message.
>
> To run BCML all you need to do is type bcml into a cmd prompt.
>
> If you would like to have a shortcut made, BCML has that option on the settings page.

Comment: This link is dead. Instead of providing link, please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.