# Installing pycuda on windows

Tags: visual-studio, pycuda

So I try `python -m pip install pycuda` and it fails (Here's some of the output from the failed install):

```
Building wheel for pycuda (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

WARNING: nvcc not in path.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycuda
Failed to build pycuda
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycuda, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have installed the Visual Studio 2022 build tools but I have not added anything to my path, which is all I figure I have todo but I don't know what I have to add. The [pycuda wiki's installation page](https://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Windows/) specifies

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;`

but I don't have those directories. Here's the tree of my visual studio install `D:\VisualStudioThings\install\VC`. (I cannot include the tree for the whole install because it's too much)

```
Common7
CoreCon
DIA SDK
ImportProjects
Licenses
Microsoft Azure Tools
MSBuild
SDK
Team Tools
VB
VC
VC#
VSSDK
Xml

VC
├───Auxiliary
│   ├───Build
│   └───VS
│       ├───include
│       │   └───CppCoreCheck
│       ├───lib
│       │   ├───arm
│       │   ├───onecore
│       │   │   ├───arm
│       │   │   ├───x64
│       │   │   └───x86
│       │   ├───x64
│       │   └───x86
│       └───UnitTest
│           ├───include
│           │   ├───UWP
│           │   └───v150
│           └───lib
│               ├───ARM
│               ├───ARM64
│               ├───UWP
│               │   ├───arm
│               │   ├───arm64
│               │   └───x64
│               ├───x64
│               └───x86
├───Redist
│   └───MSVC
│       ├───14.34.31931
│       │   ├───Auxiliary
│       │   ├───debug_nonredist
│       │   │   ├───x64
│       │   │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT
│       │   │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugCXXAMP
│       │   │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugOpenMP
│       │   │   │   └───Microsoft.VC143.OpenMP.LLVM
│       │   │   └───x86
│       │   │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT
│       │   │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugCXXAMP
│       │   │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugOPENMP
│       │   │       └───Microsoft.VC143.OpenMP.LLVM
│       │   ├───onecore
│       │   │   ├───debug_nonredist
│       │   │   │   ├───x64
│       │   │   │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT
│       │   │   │   │   └───Microsoft.VC143.DebugOpenMP
│       │   │   │   └───x86
│       │   │   │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT
│       │   │   │       └───Microsoft.VC143.DebugOPENMP
│       │   │   ├───x64
│       │   │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.CRT
│       │   │   │   └───Microsoft.VC143.OpenMP
│       │   │   └───x86
│       │   │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.CRT
│       │   │       └───Microsoft.VC143.OPENMP
│       │   ├───x64
│       │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.CRT
│       │   │   ├───Microsoft.VC143.CXXAMP
│       │   │   └───Microsoft.VC143.OpenMP
│       │   └───x86
│       │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.CRT
│       │       ├───Microsoft.VC143.CXXAMP
│       │       └───Microsoft.VC143.OPENMP
│       └───v143
└───Tools
    ├───Llvm
    │   ├───bin
    │   └───x64
    │       └───bin
    └───MSVC
        └───14.34.31933
            ├───Auxiliary
            ├───bin
            │   ├───Hostx64
            │   │   ├───x64
            │   │   │   ├───1033
            │   │   │   └───onecore
            │   │   └───x86
            │   │       └───1033
            │   └───Hostx86
            │       ├───x64
            │       │   └───1033
            │       └───x86
            │           └───1033
            ├───crt
            │   └───src
            │       ├───concrt
            │       ├───i386
            │       ├───linkopts
            │       ├───stl
            │       ├───vccorlib
            │       ├───vcruntime
            │       └───x64
            ├───include
            │   ├───cliext
            │   ├───CodeAnalysis
            │   ├───cvt
            │   ├───experimental
            │   ├───fuzzer
            │   ├───Manifest
            │   ├───msclr
            │   │   └───com
            │   └───sanitizer
            └───lib
                ├───onecore
                │   ├───arm
                │   ├───x64
                │   └───x86
                ├───x64
                │   ├───onecore
                │   ├───store
                │   └───uwp
                └───x86
                    ├───onecore
                    ├───store
                    │   └───references
                    └───uwp
```

So my question is what do I add to my path?

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

Since you are based on windows, you can try the below steps:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

`pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel`

If the above steps still don't make it work on your side, I think the issue should comes from the source doesn't have whl file. Because pip will search package from https://pypi.org/, but in this place, I don't see the package pycuda has whl there.

Based on this, I found whl file of pycuda from other place, download it and install the package via this:

`python -m pip install packagefilename.whl`

It works well on my side, I can install it at the end:

[image]

Comment: Where does one get a whl file for pycuda?

Comment: @kpie Please refer to this SO question: [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: No I haven't found a pycuda.whl file to try.

Comment: @kpie Have you checked the SO question link that I posted before, the whl can be download in [this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8C4K.png). :)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or text. They are hard to read.

Comment: @MichaelM. Hi, those are merely evidences(first image prove I meet same situation, and second one prove I finally success), main part is written via text. I know what you mean so I will not put the key part in images :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pycuda
```

Comment: If anyone can verify this it is probably the answer I'm just not on a windows system atm.