# Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, import, scipy

I have a very similar question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/python-how-do-i-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows), but I am still one step behind. I have only one version of Python 3 installed on my Windows 7 (*sorry*) 64-bit system.

I installed NumPy following this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.3.0/numpy-1.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.msi/download?use_mirror=ufpr) - as suggested in the question. The installation went fine but when I execute

```
import numpy
```

I got the following error:

> Import error: No module named numpy

Comment: Check if there's a ``numpy`` directory under ``C:\Python3x\Libs\site-packages`` (I might remember the path name wrong).

Comment: After trying many suggestions from various sites and similar questions, what worked for me was to uninstall all Python stuff and reinstall Anaconda only (see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38330088/1083292](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38330088/1083292)) The previous Python installation I had was not only redundant but only caused me trouble.

Comment: Check the libraries loaded by typing python -c 'import sys; print sys.path' - for me I realized, I used the wrong python version, had to execute the script with python3 instead of python :)

Comment: I had the same problem. I had numpy installed but was getting error 'no module named numpy'. I used pyCharm instead of VSCode and it was solved. Not sure where was the problem.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

[Support for Python 3 was added in NumPy version 1.5.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files//NumPy/1.5.0/NOTES.txt/view), so to begin with, you must download/install a newer version of NumPy.

Or simply using `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: if you use `pip3 install numpy` by default it installs the numpy version 1.18.4, use specific version instead like this - `pip install numpy==1.8.2` . check official doc for details- https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.8.2/

Comment: In my case I get "requirement already satisfied" when I install numpy. But I still get "module not found" when I try to use it.

Comment: At this time on windows, "py -m pip install numpy" is working for me. Seems python3 is no more relevent.

Answer (score 376):

You can simply use

```
pip install numpy
```

Or for python3, use

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: This worked for me after also installing python-dev, so thank you. :)

Comment: @JeremyUpsal What happens if you just use pip? Does it not install the proper version of numpy??

Comment: After doing this, and seeing it install, it still says ImportError: No module named 'numpy'. I tried installing a second time, it said it was already installed.

Comment: In my case, `pip install numpy` or `pip3 install numpy` did not work as they defaulted the installation to python 3's package folders (for unknown reasons). I used `pip2 install numpy` to resolve the errors for "no module found...".

Comment: Of course, this has to be run inside the command line/terminal. On my system (Win10), pip was not added to `PATH`. Using `where python` and changing the directory to `C:\this\excact\path\Scripts`, I was then able to use it. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41501815/4575793

Comment: pip3 install numpy" results in "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\peter\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages". You'd expect python's "import numpy" would be able to find it, but no. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'  So this answer may work in some narrow context, but not in general. There seems to be a lot more to do: configuring paths, etc.

Comment: @PeterLeopold Maybe you are having two versions of python in your system, and when you run `pip3 install numpy` the numpy package was installed into a specific version, and when you tried `import numpy` you used another python version. This happens to me all the time. Make sure that the environment / python version where you install/run the package is the same.

Comment: In my case my python script is called "test.py" -- if I opened my Anaconda prompt to my environment with numpy installed and typed "test.py" I would get the error about no module named numpy ... but if I type "python test.py" then it worked fine. Probably having to do with I installed Python via VS Community edition, and then later installed Anaconda to use Jupyter etc.

Comment: It seems unavoidable to have many different versions of python and numpy scattered all over your system. I would like to know how you can avoid this and just use one version. I also get the error "module not found" even after installing numpy.

Comment: I have 3 diff computers, one mbPro, one iMac, one Dell WS win 10, all with diff setups, some with VS Code, some pyCharm. They all have the same issue and I have tried everything that's out there, still can't fix it. Ironically it works if I run Jupyter notebook, and due to time pressue I have no time to fix it...

Comment: @AndreiMadalinButnaru Thank you. After reading your comment I went and double-checked the versions.  I had two same versions installed  (one from MS store installed probably with VS2019, and one from Python.org download executables) creating a real mess!

Comment: Experience with fresh install of Python 3.10.7 for Windows: `pip install numpy` and `pip3 install numpy` both fail; `py -m pip install numpy` works. Digging into this, "py.exe" is the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). I haven't found where my python installation actually _is_ yet.

Comment: maybe this helps someone else: if you're using Thonny: Thonny uses its own virtual environment by default. Open "Tools => Manage packages" or "Tools => Open system shell" in order to install into this environment. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240195/importing-numpy-from-thonny-modulenotfounderror)

Answer (score 39):

**Installing Numpy on Windows**

1. Open Windows command prompt with administrator privileges *(quick method: Press the Windows key. Type "cmd". Right-click on the
   suggested "Command Prompt" and select "Run as Administrator)*
2. Navigate to the Python installation directory's Scripts folder using the "cd" (change directory) command. e.g. "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PythonXX\Scripts"

This might be: *C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXX\Scripts* or *C:\Program Files (x86)\PythonXX\Scripts* (where XX represents the Python version number), depending on where it was installed. It may be easier to find the folder using Windows explorer, and then paste or type the address from the Explorer address bar into the command prompt.

3. Enter the following command: "pip install numpy".

You should see something similar to the following text appear as the package is downloaded and installed.

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.13.3-2-cp27-none-win32.whl (6.7MB)  
  100% |################################| 6.7MB 112kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.3
```

Answer (score 19):

I think there are something wrong with the installation of numpy.
Here are my steps to solve this problem.

1. go to this website to download correct package: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/
2. unzip the package
3. go to the document
4. use this command to install numpy: `python setup.py install`

Comment: unzip the package to what location?

Answer (score 17):

I also had this problem **(Import Error: No module named numpy)** but in my case it was a problem with my **PATH variables in Mac OS X**.  I had made an earlier edit to my **.bash_profile** file that caused the paths for my Anaconda installation (and others) to not be added properly.

Just adding this comment to the list here in case other people like me come to this page with the same error message and have the same problem as I had.

Comment: You explained what the problem was, but you did not explain the solution. As a Python newbie, I don't grok `the paths for my Anaconda installation` . What specifically needs to be on the PATH ?

Comment: @Cheeso I only wish I could remember now.  I presume I removed whatever edit I had made to .bash_profile and then reinstalled conda.

Answer (score 15):

You can try:

```
py -3 -m  pip install anyPackageName
```

In your case use:

```
py -3 -m  pip install numpy
```

Comment: Reader: You can replace `py -3` with `python3`

Answer (score 11):

You should try to install numpy using one of those:

```
pip install numpy
pip2 install numpy
pip3 install numpy
```

For some reason in my case pip2 solved the problem

Answer (score 10):

Faced with same issue

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

So, in our case (we are use **PIP** and python 2.7) the solution was **SPLIT** pip install commands :

From

```
RUN pip install numpy scipy pandas sklearn
```

TO

```
RUN pip install numpy scipy
RUN pip install pandas sklearn
```

Solution found here : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25193, it's related latest update of pandas to v0.24.0

Comment: just a note: the question is not strictly related to Dockerfile (even if this answer helped me, thanks Nigrimmist).

Answer (score 9):

You installed the Numpy Version for Python 2.6 - so you can only use it with Python 2.6. You have to install Numpy for Python 3.x, e.g. that one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python3.2.exe/download

For an overview of the different versions, see here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/

Comment: Thank you, I spent yesterday trying to find that version. Is there a scipy3 perchance?

Comment: yes, here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.0b2/ you just have to visit www.scipy.org, click on download, go to the sourceforge site and click through the folders to get to that version.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem too after I installed Numpy. I solved it by just closing the Python interpreter and reopening. It may be something else to try if anyone else has this problem, perhaps it will save a few minutes!

Answer (score 9):

I had numpy installed on the same environment both by pip and by conda, and simply removing and reinstalling either was not enough.

**I had to reinstall both.**

I don't know why it suddenly happened, but the solution was

```
pip uninstall numpy

conda uninstall numpy
```

uninstalling from conda also removed `torch` and `torchvision`.

then

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

and

```
pip install numpy
```

this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 7):

I too faced the above problem with phyton 3 while setting up python for machine learning.

I followed the below steps :-

Install python-2.7.13.msi

•   set PATH=C:\Python27

•   set PATH=C:\Python27\Scripts

Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Downloaded:-  -- numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

```
          --scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

Installing numpy:
pip install numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

Installing scipy:
    pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

You can test the correctness using below cmds:-

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import sklearn
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.13.1'
>>> scipy.version.version
'0.19.1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

For those using python 2.7, should try:

```
apt-get install -y python-numpy
```

Instead of pip install numpy

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly why I was getting the error, but `pip3 uninstall numpy` then `pip3 install numpy` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: pip3 may not refer to the python3 you use.
run `python3 -m pip install numpy` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Those who are using `xonsh`, do `xpip install numpy`.

Answer (score 3):

For installing NumPy via Anaconda(use below commands):

- conda install -c conda-forge numpy
- conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken numpy

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I got this even though I knew numpy was installed and unsuccessfully tried all the advice above. The fix for me was to remove the **as np**  and directly refer to modules . (python 3.4.8 on Centos)
.

```
import numpy
DataTwo=numpy.stack((OutputListUnixTwo))...
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, on windows 10, I had unknowingly installed multiple python versions (One from PyCharm IDE and another from Windows store). I uninstalled the one from windows Store and just to be thorough, uninstalled numpy `pip uninstall numpy` and then installed it again `pip install numpy`. It worked in the terminal in PyCharm and also in command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

this is the problem of the numpy's version, please check out $CAFFE_ROOT/python/requirement.txt. Then exec: sudo apt-get install python-numpy>=x.x.x, this problem will be sloved.

Comment: The user is on Windows, so `apt-get` won't help.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem as well! It turns out the problem happens when you're installing Numpy to a version of python and trying to run the program using another python version. Probably the global version of Python your text editor opens by default is different from the one that you need for the version of numpy you are running.

So to start off, run:

`which python`
`python --version`
`which pip`
`pip list`

If you can find numpy on the list, its most likely the python version you are using is not compatible with the version of numpy installed. Try switching to a different version of Python in this case.

If numpy is not installed just `pip install numpy` or `pip3 install numpy` depending upon your version of python.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use `NumPy` in `Intellij` but was facing the same issue so, I figured out that NumPy also comes with `pandas`. So, I installed pandas with `IntelliJ tip` and later on was able to import NumPy. Might help someone someday!

Answer (score 1):

I did everything from the answers here but nothing worked. So I deleted all the previous installations of numpy using the commands below.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy*
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy*
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy*
```

Then just install using pip3.

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
conda update --all
```

PS recall calling python using either "python2" or "python3" (not merely "python").

Answer (score 0):

solution for me - I installed numpy inside a virtual environment, but then running ipython was not inside virtual env:

```
(venv) ➜  which python
/Users/alon/code/google_photos_project/venv/bin/python
(venv) ➜  which ipython
/usr/bin/ipython
```

so I had to install ipython, and run ipython from the venv like this:

```
python -c 'import IPython; IPython.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()'
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, this error may refer to using the wrong python version. In my case, my environment is Windows 10 + **Cygwin**. In my Windows environment variables, the PATH points to *C:\Python38* which is correct, but when I run my command like this:

```
./my_script.py
```

I got the `ImportError: No module named numpy` because the version used in this case is Cygwin's own Python version even if PATH environment variable is correct.
All I needed was to run the script like this:

```
py my_script.py
```

And this way the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try **uninstalling** and then **reinstalling** the Python extension for VSCode.

I tried many different solutions, but this "hard refresh" was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

On MacOs, if you are getting this error in Pycharm and you installed Python3 and NumPy through Homebrew, the python interpreter path is probably not pointing to the Python interpreter that is installed by Homebrew. In Pycharm, go to `Preferences>Project: [Project Name]>Python Interpreter`, and enter `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` for the path to python interpreter.