# ImportError: No module named 'numpy.ma'

Tags: python, numpy

The full error:

```
import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "R:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "R:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 34, in <module>
    import numpy.ma as ma
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.ma'
```

numpy is imported normally.
How do I install `numpy.ma`?

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? Do check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy

Comment: How did you install numpy and matplotlib? Masked arrays have been supported since numpy v1.3 which was released in 2008, so unless you have an *extremely* old version of numpy then there is probably an issue with the installation.

Comment: It was probably a faulty install. I re-installed and it's fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same situation today. I found that I had saved a file as *numpy.py*, so check the filenames in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install the correct version of `numpy`.

download correct `.whl` file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

```
pip install C:\Path\To\Wheel\Filename.whl # for example: numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Your (via terminal) package manager and search.

Example on Ubuntu:
    aptitude search numpy

and install package.

In my case:

```
apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: `aptitude` is not pre-installed package.

Comment: You could write. I'm not David Coperfield.

Comment: You can tell based on the paths given in the traceback. It's not safe to assume that everyone else uses Ubuntu.