# How can I install NumPy on Windows using 'pip install'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-c++, numpy, pip

I want to install [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) using the `pip install numpy` command, but I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

I'm using [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) 32 bit, Python 2.7.9, pip 6.1.1 and some [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) compiler. I think it uses the compiler from [Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express), but actually I'm not sure which one, because I have several Visual Studio installations.

I know that there are prebuilt packages for Windows, but is there some way to do it just by typing `pip install numpy`?

I think that there could be other packages which must be compiled before usage, so it's not only about NumPy. I want to solve the problem with my compiler, so I could easily install any other similar package without necessity to search for prebuilt packages (and hope that there are some at all).

Comment: as per @leewz 's response, I can verify that <code>pip install numpy</code> works on windows platform.

Comment: The canonical question for this problem on Windows may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Installing extension modules can be an issue with pip.  This is why [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) exists. Conda is an open-source [BSD-licensed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) cross-platform package manager. It can easily install NumPy.

Two options:

- Install [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) [here](http://www.continuum.io/downloads)
- Install [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) [here](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/index.html) and then go to a command line and type `conda install numpy` (make sure your PATH includes the location Conda was installed to).

Comment: This article (https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/) provides lots of detail on how pip and conda work together, and why conda was created to supplement pip (e.g. to install non-Python packages, which pip can't do, and to be an environment manager as well, like virtualenv)

Comment: ATTENTION, if your errors include 'AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral' you don't need to install numpy. The problem is that you have a file in your folder called numbers.py to fix the problem simply rename your file name to my_numbers.py and numpy will work for you.

Answer (score 34):

Check the installation of Python 2.7, and then install/reinstall pip which is described [here](http://www.toptechboy.com/tutorial/python-with-arduino-lesson-6-installing-pip-on-windows/). Then a open command line windows and write:

```
pip install numpy
```

Or

```
pip install scipy
```

If already installed, try this:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can install anaconda and make my life easy in the short term but 1) I like to know what all is being installed on my machine 2) I rather know the hard way to do it in case I have to install a package that's not included in anaconda.

Comment: Oh and the process completed smoothly (windows 7). It also told me that a newer version was available and the command I should run to upgrade it.

Comment: it was weird, I tried `pip install numpy` it said __Requirement already satisfied: numpy__, I tried `pip install -U numpy` it said __Can't uninstall 'numpy'. No files were found to uninstall__  but then it continued installation __Successfully installed numpy-1.15.3__ and finally it started to work...

Comment: you should check the python version

Answer (score 22):

Frustratingly, the NumPy package published to [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) won't install on most Windows computers: *[Windows wheel package (.whl) on Pypi #5479](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5479)*

Instead:

1. Download the NumPy [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) for your Python version from *[Archived: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages, NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)*
2. Install it from the command line:

   ```
   pip install numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this—if I have Python already installed on my computer (and I do), I don't want to go downloading *another* Python distribution just to get these packages. This worked without a hitch.

Comment: the package [pipwin](https://pypi.org/project/pipwin/) automates this process.  `pip install pipwin` followed by `pipwin install numpy` should do it.

Answer (score 17):

As of March 2016, `pip install numpy` works on Windows without a Fortran compiler. See [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5479#issuecomment-193674517).

`pip install scipy` still tries to use a compiler.

July 2018: [mojoken reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499815/how-can-i-install-numpy-on-windows-using-pip-install#comment89867899_39503387) `pip install scipy` working on Windows without a Fortran compiler.

Comment: As of July 2018, pip install scipy is working fine for me on Windows without any Fortran compiler.

Answer (score 7):

```
py -m pip install numpy
```

Worked for me!

Comment: what about `py -m` makes it work, and what do they do? Please explain your answer!

Comment: 'py' is the python command line alias for windows that for one reason or another is sometimes set as a default during python installation. '-m' is mod option which allows you to run a library module as a script. 'py -m' instructs python to run the pip module as a script, passing the install and numpy keywords.

Comment: I would like to add something: For me it works with `py -<your-python-version> -m pip install numpy`. Could you edit it? Probably it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

First go through page [Download Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) to download Python 3.6.1 or 2.7.13 either of your choice. I preferred to use Python 2.7 or 3.4.4.

Now after installation, go to the folder name *python27* or *python34*, and click on the script. Now here open the command prompt by left clicking and *Run as administrator*.

After the command prompt appears, write "pip install numpy" there. This will install the latest version of NumPy and installing it will show a success comment. That's all.

Similarly, Matplotlib can be installed by just typing "pip install matplotlip". And now if you want to download [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy), then just write "pip install scipy" and if it doesn't work then you need to download Python SciPy from *[SciPy: Scientific Library for Python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/)* and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Install miniconda ([here](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/index.html))

After installed, open Anaconda Prompt (search this in Start Menu)

Write:

```
pip install numpy
```

After installed, test:

```
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem.

I decided in a very unexpected way. I just opened the command line as an administrator. And then typed:

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: pip should (mostly) never be run as Administrator. By doing so, you are ignoring the actual problems, and are causing even more problems you'll find later.