# Error upon using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use pandas python for excel manipulation.

Whenever I try to use pandas libraries, it gives me errors saying that numpy is not install.

Now when I try to do ***pip install numpy*** and ***pip install pandas***, it says Requirement already satisfied.

But when I try to do a simple numpy tutorial, it errors out on the import statement of numpy.

```
> import numpy as np
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
>    from . import multiarray
>ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>
>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
>    from . import add_newdocs
>  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
>    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
>  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
>    from .type_check import *
>  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
>    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
>  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
>    raise ImportError(msg)
>ImportError:
>Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
>Original error was: ***DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.***
```

Comment: Looks like your NumPy installation is somehow broken. Maybe force a reinstall of the package with `pip install --force-reinstall numpy` and then try again.

Comment: I have tried but I still get the error. When I perform a reinstall, I notice that when installing it says it is using the cached numpy library. I will try to get the numpy wheel and install manually. reference: 2nd answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499815/how-to-install-numpy-on-windows-using-pip-install

Comment: the answer to this is from this thread, answer by Colonel Panic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499815/how-to-install-numpy-on-windows-using-pip-install

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`
You should try it in the correct directory tho.

Comment: sweet thanks. where would that correct directory be? is it at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages ?

Comment: It should be in the Scripts dir in the Python folder. For example mine is "C:\Python27\Scripts"