# Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"; but NumPy is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, python-import

NumPy is installed via pip in Windows 7 64 bit, Python 3.

When trying to run code in the console ([Far Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Manager)), I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "[path]\X.py", line 42, in <module>
  import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I tried to install NumPy, but I failed, because it was already installed:

> pip install numpy
>
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.17.0)

This is exactly the right folder, and all other libraries work in it correctly. I tried to uninstall NumPy and then install again via `pip`, but nothing changed.

Checking Python version
`python -- version`

`Python 3.7.3`

Checking pip version
pip -V

> pip 19.2.1 from c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

There is no other Python version on my computer. I'm not sure but maybe numpy used to work before I installed `matplotlib` (via pip, of course).

Comment: What do you get if you do `python -m pip install numpy`?

Comment: checked your environment variable 'path' under the system settings? are python/scripts etc. folders specified correctly?

Comment: you have to install numpy using pip3 since you are using python3

Comment: @Nagaraju: I think this applies for Linux, where Python 2 ships with the distribution. Not necessary on Windows afaik. But well... maybe give it a try.

Comment: [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows) this question @MrFuppes

Comment: @Nagaraju, thanks for the link. As the question there states, Py2 is used in combination with Py3 installations. Not the case for this question. Also, on my Windows machine where I only run Py3, I never had to call `pip` as `pip3`. But I'd rather not be 100% sure so as I wrote, give it a try.

Comment: @MrFuppes you are right. That is worth a try.

Comment: @AlexVestin, with "python -m pip install numpy" same result as above in my question.

Comment: @Nagaraju, tryed "pip3", same result.
>check this question MrFuppes - 
tryed type "where python" in console, result
>c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Could it be because you installed a 32 bit version of Python?

Comment: Hey are you sure you got the error in the line 'import numpy'. Just making sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install numpy on windows using pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499815/how-to-install-numpy-on-windows-using-pip-install)

Comment: @Praind, thanks you very much, I was stupid. There is no problem in 32-bit version of Python, but few days ago I installed 64-bit version together with Visual Studio, not for purpose. Uninstalled it and now everything is fine.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found the issue!

Comment: The canonical question for this problem (on Windows, as this question) may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 3):

I was wrong. There was another Python version, 64-bit, in the Visual Studio folder.

I uninstalled it, and now the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The PyPI NumPy package, which is automatically downloaded by pip, does not install correctly on Windows 7.  I usually recommend that people install Python using the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), because it comes with NumPy pre-installed.

Since you already have the Python interpreter installed, you can download the NumPy [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) from [Christoph Gohlke's page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install it that way.  Be sure to use pip to uninstall the current non-working version first.

Have a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29499815/3254859), and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587391/3254859) for more details.