# Cant import numpy or install numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-import, python-install

I am using Python 3.8.0

[I am trying to import Numpy in Python Shell but got this error: " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja7U6.png)

[So I tried installing numpy in cmd by typing "pip install numpy" but I got this error: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asjnu.png)

[Then I tried typing also in cmd "python -m pip install --user numpy"
But I got this long error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 ...."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkpHl.png)

Is there a way I can get numpy running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install numpy on windows using pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499815/how-to-install-numpy-on-windows-using-pip-install)

Comment: py -3.8 -m pip install numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [install NumPy from Pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499815/how-to-install-numpy-on-windows-using-pip-install) you would need a C / C++ compiler and make sure that Python finds it. Alternatively, a much easier approach is to get a Python installation with pre-compiled NumPy. Popular such choices are:

- [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)
- [Python(x,y)](https://python-xy.github.io/)
- [ActivePython](https://www.activestate.com/products/activepython/)

more are listed in the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDistributions).

None of them offers Python 3.8 yet, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

On windows installing scientific packages, like numpy, can be a bit tricky you can try anaconda instead https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/