# How to make pip run a specific command from requirements file?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I would like to add lines for `torch` and `torchvision` on my requirements.txt file, to allow for easy clone, and I will be moving from computer to computer and to cloud in the near future.

I want an easy `pip install -r requirements.txt` and be done with it for my project.

```
> pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

gives something like

```
...
torch==1.5.0
torchvision==0.6.0
...
```

However, `pip install -r requirements.txt` (which is in fact `pip install torch`) doesn't work, and instead, as the [official torch site](https://pytorch.org/), clearly says the command should be:

```
pip install torch===1.5.0 torchvision===0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

How do I make the requirements file reflect this?

My desktop is Windows 10.

---

Bonus question:

My cloud is Linux based.
How do I make the requirements file fit both desktop and cloud?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the error message you get?

Comment: @DavidZ Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
No matching distribution found for torch===1.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))

Comment: Oh, I meant edit it into the question. Information in comments may be lost after a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can use the same options in your `requirements.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format), *e.g.*

```
torch===1.5.0
torchvision===0.6.0
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Then simply run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: nice. What about a version that is OS sensitive, or better, OS insensitive?

Comment: Also feasible on a _per line_ basis

Comment: @michaeldel Ok, Can you explain please why the commands in the official site are different? just for beauty for the linux users?

Comment: The specified packages may require external libraries (as binary or as source to compile) that might not get properly installed on Windows with `pip`, hence the `-f` requirement linking to compiled wheel files. See this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/29503549/1812262

Comment: @sinoroc actually doesn't work inline with same error as I posted in my question.