# Specify -f option in pip3 requirements.txt

Tags: pip, pytorch, requirements.txt, torchvision

I used to install PyTorch with the command:

```
pip3 install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I want to save the requirements into a requirements.txt file.
How can I include the `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` option?

I tried:

```
torchvision==0.8.2+cu110  --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and

```
torch==1.7.1+cu110 --install-option="--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html"
torchvision==0.8.2+cu110  --install-option="--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html"
```

but they give me the following error when running `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py:182: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options, line.opts)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.1+cu110 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.1+cu110
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch+requirements.txt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582065/8211365