# ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.8.2

Tags: python, pip, torchvision

torchvision 0.8.2 [exists](https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/0.8.2/)

But when running `pip install torchvision==0.8.2`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.8.2 (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 
0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.5.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.8.2
```

I'm using `Python 3.8.2`.

Any reason why the version is available on PyPi but it doesn't work with pip install?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/0.8.2/#files See the list of available Python versions, OS and processor architectures.

Comment: What should I do with that?

Comment: Should I download it?

Comment: You should correlate the list with your Python version, OS and processor architecture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69353539/7976758 See how people install it from download.pytorch.org. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip+torchvision