# running python script on HPC

Tags: python, r, bash

I am working on HPC and getting an error while running the python script?
could you please suggest what module should I need to load? or do we need to again install pandas? although I also have loaded the numpy?

module load  libs/numpy/1.7.1/gcc-4.8.5+python-2.7.8+atlas-3.10.3

```
$ python filter_repophlan.py -r repophlan_microbes_wscores.txt -s 0.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter_repophlan.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/opt/apps/Python-Packages/pandas/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Many thanks

Comment: 1) Upgrade to Python3.5+, 2) Install Anaconda3 or Miniconda3, 3) If Miniconda, install `numpy` and `pandas` using `conda install`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas - Missing required dependencies \['numpy'\] 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859939/python-pandas-missing-required-dependencies-numpy-1)