# Python - Numpy Module Not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I applied chi - square test and after running successful few minutes ago now it is showing me the error. The program shows me the error in numpy.

The error I observed is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Setups\Python\chi-1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL
  File "G:\Setups\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "G:\Setups\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "G:\Setups\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "G:\Setups\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "G:\Setups\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._internal import TooHardError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._internal'
```

The code I performed:

```
import numpy
```

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy

Comment: I already did this. Still Same error

Comment: Looks like a broken numpy. Looks like you're running on Windows, so try to pip uninstall and install again numpy.

Answer (score 1):

conda install -c conda-forge numpy

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the `numpy` package from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

I was running to a similar problem while implementing some stuff related to empirical distributions.

Remember, you'll have to download the wheel and install it with `pip install numpy_*****.whl`, it might also be the case with `scipy` if you're using it. I hope it solves your problem.