# Importing numpy from Thonny: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, numpy, module

I typed into the command prompt:
C:\Users\JoshPC>pip install numpy

and it said:

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\joshpc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages

Then in Thonny I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
```

and I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

So it's some kind of path error, but I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thonny uses its own virtual environment by default. Open "Tools => Manage packages" or "Tools => Open system shell" in order to install into this environment.

Comment: For completeness I will add that once you are in the Thonny System Shell you can run either "pip" or "pip3" to install the module you need.
For example:
"pip3 install requests" OR "pip install requests" to install the HTTP requests module.

Answer (score 0):

delete the numpy packages in site-packages manually, and install numpy again using pip

```
pip install numpy
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for responding ... but unfortunately I get the same error as before. ModuleNotFound

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your python is in the path.
following steps will make it easier to install any dependency

- While installing python change path to `C:\Python`

  you can install anything with pip like

  `c:\Python>pip install numpy
   c:\Python>pip install 'any_dependency'`