# numpy installed, but module not found error

Tags: numpy, modulenotfounderror

This is the error I'm getting when trying to run my code.

PS E:\projects\supply-chain-management\LSTM> python3 .\LSTM.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:\projects\supply-chain-management\LSTM\LSTM.py", line 3, in <module>
import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

PS E:\projects\supply-chain-management\LSTM> pip3 install numpy

Requirement already satisfied:

numpy in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (1.26.3)

I've installed numpy. The module shows up as installed when I try to install it again.

Comment: Are you using any IDE for running your code? Many IDE create project wise virtual environments. Your numpy is installed in the python which you've installed in your system. But there is a possibility that the interpreter you are using is in a virtual env and numpy is not there.

Can you please share more details related to your IDE or whether you are using virtual env or not?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240195/importing-numpy-from-thonny-modulenotfounderror?rq=2
In this case, Thony (an IDE) was used which uses separate virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the numpy package inside the scripts folder which is present in the python setup folder
that is :

Python\Python312\Scripts

use cmd prompt inside the folder and try installing it using pip3 install numpy

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: This is what I'm getting after "pip3 install numpy" in the Scripts file.

C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts>pip3 install numpy

Requirement already satisfied: 

numpy in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (1.26.3)

Comment: Is the package still not getting imported  if so what is the output message that is printed on it

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'