# Mac OS X: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

After I have reinstalled [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), I can not import NumPy any more on Python 3:

```
import numpy as np
```

Output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have tried

```
pip install numpy
```

I try to install it again, but I get:

```
pip install numpy
```

Output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.16.3)
```

#### Screenshot of some of the above

[image]

Comment: And what did `numpy` installed correctly? Are you in a virtual environment? Have you tried `pip3 install numpy`?

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question but when you call Python, you use `python3` in your shell? Maybe you have previous versions installed

Comment: Yes I do. I added the screenshot of my terminal

Comment: The canonical question for this problem on ***Windows*** may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 3):

This command worked for me

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You probably have multiple NumPy versions installed on your system and need to manually delete the old one.

1. Open `Terminal` and run:

   pip list
2. Remember or notate the NumPy version from the list
3. Then run `Python` in `Terminal` or write and execute this code in your IDE:

   import numpy

   print(numpy)
   print(numpy.**version**)
4. This should print two lines: `numpy package location` + `numpy version` like this:

   <module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/**init**.pyc'>
   1.16.1
5. If the NumPy version reported here is different than the one reported by `pip list`, then go to the NumPy package location printed above and delete that package folder
6. Try importing NumPy now. If you previously installed it, it should work. If you didn't install it then go and install it now. After installation all should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment to run your program. So you should run:

```
conda install numpy
```

If you use IDE like [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), it will be easy to install packages by a mouse click ([Install packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)).