# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" for Python 3.7.3 on Mac

Tags: python, numpy

I am following instructions to make a very simple neural network program, and I keep getting an error from my line to import NumPy.

```python
import numpy as np
```

I always get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

When I use the Mac console and type `import numpy`, it works fine.

When I am typing the import statement in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) and type it slowly to see what intellisense suggests, it suggests "numbers" or "enum", but NumPy is not there.

When I use the Mac console, I can write `import numpy` without any problems.

I checked the class-path and it appears to include the [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) folders, which is where NumPy is.

- Python version: 3.7.3
- NumPy version: 1.16.4
- [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave)

Comment: Related (2019): *[Mac OS X: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252299/mac-os-x-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy)*

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed NumPy like,

`pip install NumPy`

or

`pip3 install NumPy`

that will most likely be the answer.

If you have I would suggest reinstalling the NumPy package:

`pip reinstall numpy`

or

`pip3 reinstall numpy`

Another thing is just try to look at the NumPy page, and search for anything else that might help you!

Comment: [Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). Meta information does not belong in posts, only in comments (or at all).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Confused on where I put `Meta Information`, but :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

Python looks for modules in every directory listed in `sys.path`. The Python binary (and module paths) are almost certainly different for PyCharm and the system installed (Terminal) environments.

You will have to install NumPy within PyCharm. Alternately, you can use `sys.path.append(0,'/path/to/numpy')` or (in Bash) `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/numpy` to temporarily extend the `sys.path` array to point to another distribution of NumPy on your system.

Answer (score -2):

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but there wasn't any difference.

[Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) doesn't have any problem with the *import* statement. It's only PyCharm, so I will stick to Atom.