# No module named 'numpy' but Requirement already satisfied: numpy

Tags: python

When I want to execute my script I got the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. But the module is already installed as said me the answer to the install command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\simeo\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages (1.17.2)
```

I'm quite new with Python, so I don't understand why it's not working and what could be the problem.

I'm using Windows 10 (64 bits). I installed Python 3.7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one Python installation?

Comment: How can I check that? In my start folder I only have one Python.

Comment: check the used python version in pip with `pip --version` and compare it with the version of python checked with `python --version`.

Comment: pip version : 3.5 ; python version : 3.5.6
So it's not exactly same, and different from the version I have according my Python folder in start menu

Comment: It should be the same because pip don't show the minor versions `.6`.

Comment: Try to compare the path of the packages with `pip --version` and `python -m site`.

Comment: Looks like you have anaconda as per your pip output. How did you install python 3.7? What's the output when you run `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Comment: @raze92 : I got several paths with that command. Which one I have to check?
@JustinEzequiel: I got that answer `C:/Users/simeo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe h:/ProjetDev/Python/temp/test.py
C:\Users\simeo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe`
I installed Python some months ago with the installer I found on Python website.

Comment: For the same ***symptom***, the canonical question for this problem (on Windows, as this question) may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows** try either two of these methods in cmd:

1. `pip3 install numpy`
2. `pip3 install -U numpy`
3. directly download latest version from sourceforge.net

If you are using pycharm, it can not install numpy from interpreter settings. After one of above method works, try installing numpy in pycharm again through interpreter settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Numpy library. Your current Keras version is not compatible with your Numpy module. You can use the below-given command to upgrade Numpy.`pip install -U numpy`

Answer (score 0):

You may have different version of python with different location which means that when you install numpy it gets installed for a different version of python with which you are trying to run your script

try to run

```bash
pip show <package name>
```

And look at location to check if it is the location of the python version you are trying to use.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this to your code, above everything else:

```
import numpy
```