# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I tried importing NumPy to carry out some array operations in Python:

`import numpy *`

But I got this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

What do I do?

Comment: [the official installation instructions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html) may be of use.

Comment: You have not installed numpy module or you are using the wrong python installation.

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy

Comment: The canonical question for this problem on Windows may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), open PyCharm and go to menu *File* → *Setting* → *Project* → *Python Interpreter* → *click on '+'* → search and select the required package → install package.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command

```
pip3 install numpy
```

You will get the following response. You see the location.

Use the following as PATH as per direction explained in the previous post.

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\-user name-\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.20.1)
```

NumPy is installed here, not in "scripts".

Comment: What should we have to do in this case

Answer (score 1):

NumPy doesn't seem to be installed on your computer, but you can use this command to install it:

```
python -m pip install --user numpy
```

Or you can check the installation guide for your distribution here:
[Install SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install NumPy with pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [NumPy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) with the `pip install numpy` command (ignore if already installed).

Import NumPy in either of the three ways:

- `import numpy`
- `import numpy as np`
- `from numpy import *`