# No module named 'numpy.linalg'; 'numpy' is not a package

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get started with matplotlib. Its showing error of :

```
>import matplotlib as plt
  File "C:\Users\ishwa\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\ishwa\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\ishwa\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\ishwa\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\ishwa\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 138, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\ishwa\env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 46, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import inv
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.linalg'; 'numpy' is not a package**
```

I tried installing numpy and matplotlib both to root and virtual env... But nothing seems to be working

Comment: Confirm if the python executable has access to the installation location of numpy. check for multiple versions held. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575113/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy

Comment: Can [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333865/python-no-module-named-error-package-is-not-a-package) solve your problem?