# Numpy and open cv not importing

Tags: python, numpy, new-operator

I'm fairly new to programming and need help I've installed pip and I have installed NumPy using

`pip install numpy`

and when I try to import it in my code I get

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'' (also the same for cv2)

if this is any help

I've installed pip, anaconda, and tensor flow 2.0 GPU

My os is Windows 10

any help is good thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Error: No module named numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running through anaconda, you should strictly use conda to install packages instead of pip. Using both will confuse python and give a 'module not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex Tejada mentioned I recommend to use conda install, so for numpy according to their [website](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy) this would be: `conda install -c anaconda numpy`, which can be typed into your anaconda prompt. If you have multiple environments, make sure to activate the correct one before installing. I recommend [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-keras-tensorflow-using-anaconda-for-machine-learning-44ab28ff39cb) tutorial here for tensorflow and anaconda.