# Error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.array'; 'numpy' is not a package"

Tags: python, numpy, modulenotfounderror

Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(a)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeffhacks\Desktop\np.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Jeffhacks\Desktop\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy.array as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.array'; 'numpy' is not a package
```

But, I already installed NumPy in my pc. How can I solve this bug?

Comment: It is because you have a file `numpy.py` in your desktop .remove that file or rename and try again

Comment: The canonical question for a slightly related problem on Windows may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to a *circular import*. This means that there is a file named *numpy.py* in the current directory (folder) and in *np.py* when you are using 'import numpy' it is actually importing *numpy.py*, not the actual module.

To prevent this, just change the name of the *numpy.py* file to something else.

*Never* name a Python file with module names.

Answer (score 0):

Also to fix this, install [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) inside of Visual Studio Code and then set it to run inside the integrated terminal using the settings inside of VSCode. Once you have installed Code Runner, use

```
python3.7 -m pip install numpy
```

to install inside of the terminal, and it should download correctly. Then run using the correct entry point in your files.