# How to import in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am self-learning Python and all the online courses use labs where all libraries are already imported. Whenever I try to import numpy or pandas or any other library I receive this message:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in 
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[import-error-no-module-named-numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy)

ModuleNotFoundError is thrown when a module could not be found
Support for Python 3 was added in NumPy version 1.5.0

you do not install numpy Correctly

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip3 install numpy
```

I strongly recommend you use Virtualenv to install it numpy

```
pip install virtualenv
```

go to folder of your code use

`virtualenv venv`

//Windows

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

//Linux

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

you can use conda to install numpy

download conda from here [coda GUI installer](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#macos)

Best practice, use an environment rather than install in the base env

```
conda create -n my-env
conda activate my-env
```

If you want to install from conda-forge

```
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
```

The actual install command

```
conda install numpy
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the pip3 install numpy and it says "syntax error". Could you explain more about conda? I use Mac. @MehrdadLinux

Comment: @SharafY.Yassin use link in my post it is very useful ,i update my post follow the link