# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named numpy as np

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Visual Studio Code and try to 'import cv2', but I see an error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def sketch(image):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5,5), 0)
    canny_edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray_blur, 10, 70)
    ret, mask = cv2.threshold(canny_edges, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    return mask
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: It looks like you installed `opencv-python` but didn't install `numpy` yet. Since your shared code doesn't even use `numpy`, you could just remove the import line, or install numpy using `pip`, `conda` or whatever you use to install packages.

Comment: Slightly different error message, but the canonical question for a related problem on Windows may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 2):

You have to to your `cmd.exe`, or if you are not in windows you simply have to go to your command prompt.

```
pip install numpy
```

And after writing this in the prompt, try another time to run your Python file.

Comment: What do you mean by *"You have to to your..."*?. Do you mean *"You have to go to your..."* Or something else?

Comment: Perhaps rephrase so it does not appear it is for Windows only?

Comment: On other OSs it's py -m pip install numpy, right?