# After building dockerfile: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, docker, numpy, pyspark

I have to run the python program in Redhat8. So I pull Redhat docker image and write a Dockerfile which is in the following:

```
  FROM redhat/ubi8:latest
  RUN echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf && mkdir /home/spark && mkdir /home/spark/spark && mkdir /home/spark/ETL && mkdir /usr/lib/java && mkdir /usr/share/oracle

  # set environment vars
  ENV SPARK_HOME /home/spark/spark
  ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/java

  # install packages
  RUN \
    echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf && \
    yum install -y rsync && yum install -y wget && yum install -y python3-pip && yum 
    install -y openssh-server && yum install -y openssh-clients && \
    yum install -y unzip && yum install -y python38 && yum install -y nano 
    # create ssh keys
    RUN \
    echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf && \
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    # copy ssh config
    COPY ssh_config /root/.ssh/config
    COPY spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz /home/
    COPY jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz  /home/
    COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip /home
    COPY etl /home/ETL/

    RUN \
    tar -zxvf /home/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz -C /home/spark && mv -v 
    /home/spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/* $SPARK_HOME && tar -zxvf /home/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /home/spark && mv -v /home/spark/jdk1.8.0_25/* $JAVA_HOME && unzip /home/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /home/spark && mv -v /home/spark/instantclient_19_8 /usr/share/oracle && echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc && \
   echo "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:/usr/share/oracle/instantclient_19_8" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/share/oracle/instantclient_19_8" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc

  #WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `python3.8 -m pip install --user` instead.
  # so I have to create a user
  RUN echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf 
  RUN useradd -d /home/spark/myuser myuser
  USER myuser
  WORKDIR /home/spark/myuser
  ENV PATH="/home/spark/myuser/.local/bin:$PATH"
  RUN \  
  python3.8 -m pip install --user pandas && \ 
  python3.8 -m pip install --user cx-Oracle && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user persiantools && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user pyspark && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user py4j && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user python-dateutil && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user pytz && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user setuptools && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user six && \
  python3.8 -m pip install --user numpy


   # copy spark configs
  ADD spark-env.sh $SPARK_HOME/conf/
  ADD workers $SPARK_HOME/conf/
  
  # expose various ports
  EXPOSE 7012 7013 7014 7015 7016 8881 8081 7077
```

Also, I copy and build the dockerfile with this script:

```
  #/bin/bash

  cp /etc/ssh/ssh_config .
  cp /opt/spark/conf/spark-env.sh .
  cp /opt/spark/conf/workers .
  sudo docker build -t my_docker .
  echo "Script Finished."
```

The dockerfile built without any error. Then I make a tar file from the image that made with this command:

```
  sudo docker save my_docker > my_docker.tar
```

After that I copy the *my_docker.tar* to the another computer and load it:

```
  sudo docker load < my_docker.tar
  sudo docker run -it my_docker
```

Unfortunately, when I run my program inside docker container, I receive errors about python package like numpy,pyspark,pandas.

```
  File "/home/spark/ETL/test/main.py", line 3, in <module>
  import cst_utils as cu
  File "/home/spark/ETL/test/cst_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
  import group_state as gs
  File "/home/spark/ETL/test/group_state.py", line 1, in <module>
  import numpy as np
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I also try to install the python packages in the docker container and then commit the container.But, when I exit from the container and enter again, there is no python package installed.

Would you please guide what is wrong with my way?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the `CMD` in the Dockerfile; what is the main container process?  How much of the Dockerfile is actually necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: By the way, `pip install` accepts multiple parameters at once... And why do you keep editing the resolv.conf?

Comment: @DavidMaze I assume OP is doing `docker run` / `exec`, then `python` or `spark-submit`

Comment: Dear @OneCricketeer, thank you for your feedback. I test the redhat image that if set **nameserver 9.9.9.9** in **/etc/resolv.conf**, I can install the package via internet.Also, every time that I use **RUN** command **/etc/resolv.conf** create a gain, so I add **nameserver 9.9.9.9** in  **/etc/resolv.conf** file each time that I want to install packages. And you are right, I want to use ```docker run / exec ``` and then ```spark-submit``` to run the program.

Comment: The Docker container should use your hosts own DNS resolver, so sounds like you have a separate network issue. No RUN command that you're using should be changing that file either

Comment: The canonical question for this problem on ***Windows*** may be *[Error "Import Error: No module named numpy" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/)* (2011, 40 answers and 300 votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I changed the Dockerfile.
First, I did not define any user. Then, I set **PYSPARK_PYTHON**, so there was not error about importing any packages.
The Dockerfile is like this:

```
 FROM redhat/ubi8:latest
 RUN echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf 
 RUN mkdir /home/spark &&  mkdir /home/ETL && mkdir /usr/lib/java && mkdir /usr/share/oracle
 # set environment vars
 ENV SPARK_HOME /home/spark
 ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/java
 # install packages
 RUN \
 echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf && \
 yum -y update  && \
 yum install -y libaio && \
 yum install -y libaio.so.1 && \
 dnf install libnsl* && \
 yum install -y rsync && yum install -y wget && yum install -y python3-pip && yum install -y openssh-server && yum install -y openssh-clients && \
 yum install -y unzip && yum install -y python38 && yum install -y nano 
 #WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `python3.8 -m pip install --user` instead.
 # It is just a warning
 RUN echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf && \
 python3.8 -m pip install pandas && \ 
 python3.8 -m pip install cx-Oracle && \
 python3.8 -m pip install persiantools && \
 python3.8 -m pip install pyspark && \
 python3.8 -m pip install py4j && \
 python3.8 -m pip install python-dateutil && \
 python3.8 -m pip install pytz && \
 python3.8 -m pip install setuptools && \
 python3.8 -m pip install numpy && \
 python3.8 -m pip install six
 # create ssh keys
 RUN echo "nameserver 9.9.9.9" >> /etc/resolv.conf && \
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
 chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

  # copy ssh config
 COPY ssh_config /root/.ssh/config
 COPY spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz /home
 COPY jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz  /home
 COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip /home
 COPY etl /home/ETL/
 RUN \
 tar -zxvf /home/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz -C /home && mv -v /home/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/* $SPARK_HOME && tar -zxvf /home/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /home && mv -v /home/jdk1.8.0_25/* $JAVA_HOME && unzip /home/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /home 
 RUN \  
 echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc && \
 echo "export SPARK_HOME=$SPARK_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc && \
 echo "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:/home/instantclient_21_4" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/instantclient_21_4" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc && \
 echo "export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:/usr/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc

 ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/instantclient_21_4"
 ENV PYTHONPATH = "$SPARK_HOME/python:/usr/bin/python3.8"
 ENV PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:/home/instantclient_21_4"

 RUN \
 touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/instantclient.conf && \
 echo "#path of instant client" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/instantclient.conf && \
 echo "/home/instantclient_21_4" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/instantclient.conf && \
 ldconfig

 # copy spark configs
 ADD spark-env.sh $SPARK_HOME/conf/
 ADD workers $SPARK_HOME/conf/

 # expose various ports
 EXPOSE 7012 7013 7014 7015 7016 8881 8081 7077
```

I hope it was useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from any issues with the Dockerfile setup itself,

In your `spark-env.sh`, set these to make sure it is using the same environment where pip had installed to

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.8"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.8"
```

Keep in mind that SparkSQL Dataframes should really be used *instead of* `numpy`, and you don't need to `pip install pyspark` since it is already part of the downloaded spark package.

Comment: I edit **spark-env.sh** as you said, but the problem stay the same.

Comment: I think you should focus on the actual code. What specific reason are you using numpy rather than SparkSQL?

Comment: I don't have experience about SparkSQL, so I use numpy and pandas Dataframe.

Comment: Then you're not really "using Spark" properly then. Numpy/Pandas are not distributed until you add Koalas https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/10min.html

Comment: Dear @OneCricketeer, thank you for suggestion, I'll check Koalas.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your code, removing most stuff that seemed (to me) irrelevant to the problem.

I found that moving

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc
```

down, after `USER myuser` solved it. Before it I got `python` not found, and `python3` turned out not to have have numpy either, whereas `python3.8` did. So there was some confusion there, maybe in your full example something happens that obscures this even more.

But try to move that statement because `~/.bashrc` is NOT the same when you change user.

Comment: I did what you had told. In fact, when I run ```import numpy``` in **python environment**, I did not receive any error. But, when I run the program with ```spark-submit``` , I received **No module named 'numpy'**.