# scipy installation in ubuntu 14.04 failed

Tags: python, scipy, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 through VMWare Workstation 11 and virtual env and I've tried to install `scipy` via:

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

and got this as console output:

```
  Downloading scipy-0.17.0.tar.gz (12.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.4MB 115kB/s 
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-C9op9y/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4yRNRk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1542: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1553: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1556: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-C9op9y/scipy/setup.py", line 265, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-C9op9y/scipy/setup.py", line 262, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-C9op9y/scipy/setup.py", line 182, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-C9op9y/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4yRNRk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-C9op9y/scipy/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly openBLAS isn't installed.
You can get it from http://www.openblas.net/ and then compile it from source.

A much easier way to install scipy is of course just

```
apt-get install python-scipy
```

Comment: This works but is going to install a somewhat outdate version. One can do `apt-get build-dep python-scipy` and *then* pip install scipy

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114225/installing-scipy-and-numpy-using-pip), some external packages are needed.

The full install guide is [over there](http://www.scipy.org/install.html), but the validated answer on the previous link provides good insights.