# Install scipy for both python 2 and python 3

Tags: python, scipy, debian

I used `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` to install scipy. This put all the files in `/usr/lib/python2.7.dist-packages/scipy`. My best guess is it chose that location because python 2.7 was the default version of python. I also want to use scipy with python 3 however. Does the package need to be rebuilt for python 3 or can I just point python 3 to the existing version?

I've tried using pip to install two parallel version, but I can't get the dependency `libblas3` installed for my system.

What's the best way to do this?

I'm on Debian Jessie.

Comment: To install scipy for python3.x the on a debian-based distribution: `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`

Comment: You can just invoke pip with the python version of your choice `sudo python -m pip install scipy`. Just use python3 if you want the python 3 installation.

Comment: @M.T I think this is the preferred option. Several other SO questions have pointed out that pip doesn't run real smoothly with scipy. (eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114225/installing-scipy-and-numpy-using-pip) Its weird that this is never mentioned on the scipy install page. If you'd like to list this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To install scipy for python3.x the on a debian-based distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

This corresponds to the python2.x equivalent:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

On a more platform-independent note, `pip` is the more standard way of installing python packages:

```
    pip install --user scipy #pip install using default python version
```

To make sure you are using the right pip version you can always be more explicit:

```
    pip2 install --user scipy  # install using python2
    pip3 install --user scipy  # install using python3
```

Also, I believe anaconda or the more lightweight [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) were intended to make installation of python packages with complex dependencies more easy, plus it allows for using an environment, making it easier to have several configurations with non-compatible versions etc. This would create+use a python binary different from the one on your system though.

One would then install scipy using the command conda:

```
conda install scipy
```

If installing scipy for a specific version you would create an environment with that python version:

```
conda create -n my_environment_name python=3 scipy
```

One could also use pip inside a conda environment alongside conda python packages, but I would make sure that you are using pip installed using conda to avoid conflicts. An added benefit when installing conda for a user, is that you don't have to add the `--user` flag when installing with pip.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find `python3-scipy` using apt-get you can use pip to install it for python3, you just have to make sure you use pip3 (if you don't have it `apt install python3-pip`

```
pip3 install --user scipy
```

Comment: `sudo pip` is a recipe for future pain, use `pip install --user`

Comment: Thank you! Took a look at the scripy instillation and it says to use `pip install --user` , oops!

Comment: thank you it worked after login mysel as administrator in the windows command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with `pip3 install scipy`