# Add Python 2.7.6 to the windows registry

Tags: windows, python-2.7, registry, py2exe

I've installed Python 2.7.6 onto my Windows 7 32bit system, but it does not seem to have added it to the registry.

When I tried installing py2exe (a version appropriate for 2.7.6 on 32bit) it keeps saying I need Python 2.7 which was not found in the registry.

Could anyone provide me with a list of the registry items that need to be in place or have a simple app that modifies the registry to that I can install py2exe?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry" error when attempting to install netCDF4 on Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169582/python-version-2-7-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry-error-when-at)

Answer (score 4):

Installing py2exe (py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe) requires:

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Python27" /f

Tested on Windows 10.

Regards
LO

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should to add python dir path to system variables

[Look this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/1897374)

Comment: Tried that. No go, py2exe installer still says that it could not find it in the registry.  The version I'm trying to load is py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe.  My Python is in the directory: C:\Program Files\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6   I checked by registry using regedit and can find no main entries for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out WinPython has a menu option in the Control Console for adding Python packages that not only registers python for redistribution, but also registers it in the Windows Registry.  Once I ran that menu option the install went ahead just fine.
Why WinPython doesn't add itself during installation I'll never know.  A caution to others, don't assume any installation does it all, you may still need to run a registry app.