# Installation of py2

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I want to transform a python script in a executable file. That is why, I want to install py2exe
When I try to install the file "py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe", I got the message "Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry"

I suspect that py2exe is not finding my python.exe file (it ask me python directory but I cannot enter anything).
Python 2.7.9 is installed on my laptop in the file Mydocuments (and I cannot not move the path)!
I use Windows 8.

Thank you a lot for your help and for your answer

Comment: Are you running 64-Bit Python, by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169582/python-version-2-7-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry-error-when-at

Comment: Thanks SiHa for your answer. I use a 32 bit Python so the problem is not here. However, in the link that you gave, duhaime gave a solution to change the path to go to python and now I can run py2.exe file". Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Just unpack this exe with tool like **7-zip** and you can run py2exe from resulting folder.